# Is it possible to call one option and it's argument for more times in one command?

Tags: bash, getopt

It is my bash case `test-getopt.sh` to understand getopt in bash.

```
OPTS=$(getopt -o d:eh   -- "$@")
eval set -- "$OPTS"
while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -d ) 
            if [[ $2  ==  "a"  ]];then
                echo  "i am -d's arg :a"
            elif [[ $2  ==  "b"  ]];then
                echo  "i am -d's arg :b"
            fi
            shift;;
        -e )   
            echo "i  am e"
            shift;;
        -h)
            echo "help you"
            shift;;
        -- ) 
            shift;; 
        *)
            break;;
    esac
done
```

To call for option and it's argument,one option and it's argument for one time.

```
bash test-get.sh  -d  a
i am -d's arg :a
```

Other argument.

```
bash test-get.sh  -d  b
i am -d's arg :b
```

I want to call option and it's all argument in one command

```
bash test-get.sh  -d  a -d b
i am -d's arg :a
```

Is there a way to get the following expect output?

```
bash test-get.sh  -d  a -d b
i am -d's arg :a
i am -d's arg :b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that when you process an option that takes an argument, you need to `shift` twice to remove both the option *and its argument* from the arg list. Like this:

```
OPTS=$(getopt -o d:eh   -- "$@")
eval set -- "$OPTS"
while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -d ) 
            if [[ $2  ==  "a"  ]];then
                echo  "i am -d's arg :a"
            elif [[ $2  ==  "b"  ]];then
                echo  "i am -d's arg :b"
            fi
            shift 2;;   # <-- The "2" here is the only change
        -e )   
            echo "i  am e"
            shift;;
        -h)
            echo "help you"
            shift;;
        -- ) 
            shift;; 
        *)
            break;;
    esac
done
```

Without the double shift, what happens is that on the first time through the loop the arg list is "-d" "a" "-d" "b" "--". You detect the "-d" and "a", print appropriately, and then shift, which leaves the arg list as "a" "-d" "b" "--". On the second time through the loop, it fails to match "a" as an option, executes the `*)` case, and breaks out of the processing loop.

Comment: I believe `shift; shift;;` would work also, although of course `shift 2;;` is easier. +1